# How to remove spaces between two div in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML/CSS code to get pink band and a black smaller band without spaces.
This is my CSS and HTML code
The problem is I am getting spaces between the two dives, I tried many solutions from the net but without result.

Any help please ?

```css
.my_bande_rose    {  background-color: #E6007E; 
                     height: 124px; 
                     width:  100%; 
                     margin-top: 0;
                     margin-bottom: 0;
                     padding-top: 0;
                     padding-bottom: 0;                     
                  }
.bande_horizontale{  float: right;
                     width: 83.4%; 
                     height: 5px; 
                     background-color: #000000; 
                     margin-top: 0;
                     margin-bottom: 0;
                     padding-top: 0;
                     padding-bottom: 0;                     
                  } 
 .my_logo         {  height: 124px;
                     width:225px;
                     top: 0px;
                     float:left;
                  }
 .my_title        {  width:260px;
                     float:right;
                     margin:25px auto;
                     font-weight:bold;
                     padding:5px;
                  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
           src="../js/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=AM_HTMLorMML-full">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div class="my_bande_rose">
<div class="my_title">
<h5 style="color:#ffffff;" >My tittle</h5>
</div><div class="my_logo">
<img src="https://www.pajemploi.urssaf.fr/pajewebdeclaratif/images/pajeweb/newletter/logo_forme.jpg" alt="Pajemploi, un service des urssaf"/>
</div><div class="bande_horizontale"></div>
</div> <br>
<h2 style="color:#E6007E;" >My tittle again</h2>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean? in my fiddle it looks great.

Comment: i don't see any white space between pink and black div....

Comment: Looks fine on my side too. No white space between pink and black.

Answer (score -1):

If you refer to the space on the left side of the black div you need to change the following `.bande_horizontale` properties:

```
float: left;
width: 100%;
```